# Is it safe to override Apache CXF's JAXRSBeanValidationInInterceptor to support request-scoped resources?

Tags: cxf, bean-validation

By default, CXF 3.0.5's `JAXRSBeanValidationInInterceptor` and `JAXRSBeanValidationOutInterceptor` do not support validation of arguments passed to request-scoped resource beans. This exclusion is enforced in `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.ValidationUtils.getResourceInstance(Message)`. Attempting to use a request-scoped resource results in the following warning being logged:

```
Service object is not a singleton, use a custom invoker to validate
```

I've spent some time poking around and come up with the following workaround:

```
/**
 * This is a replacement for CXF's builtin
 * {@link JAXRSBeanValidationInInterceptor}. This customization supports
 * validation of messages handled by non-singleton JAX-RS resource beans. This
 * is needed as many of the beans in this project are request-scoped.
 */
public class BeanValidationInInterceptor extends
        JAXRSBeanValidationInInterceptor {
    /**
     * This is a customization of the code in CXF's builtin
     * {@link ValidationUtils#getResourceInstance(Message)}.
     * 
     * @see org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.validation.JAXRSBeanValidationInInterceptor#getServiceObject(org.apache.cxf.message.Message)
     */
    @Override
    protected Object getServiceObject(Message message) {
        final OperationResourceInfo ori = message.getExchange().get(
                OperationResourceInfo.class);
        if (ori == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (!ori.getClassResourceInfo().isRoot()) {
            return message.getExchange().get(
                    "org.apache.cxf.service.object.last");
        }
        final ResourceProvider resourceProvider = ori.getClassResourceInfo()
                .getResourceProvider();

        return resourceProvider.getInstance(message);
    }
}
```

It seems to work, but as I don't fully understand the reason this wasn't supported in the first place, I'm wondering if it's safe?

Any CXF devs around who can explain if/how I'm shooting myself in the foot here, and what I might do instead?

Comment: This question needs more attention. Did you file a bug report? Your code works perfectly with resources instantiated/registered using Spring and `SpringComponentScanServer`. Thanks a lot!